# foundation media query ranges bug

Tags: html, css, sass

So i've had to fix a bug in a project built on foundation and when i finally realised what caused it, it got me thinking.

The bug was appearing betwen 1024px and 1027px width - navigation would go from mobile state to desktop but some elements would still stay as in mobile version.

In foundation _settings.scss file i found this:

```
//Media Query Ranges
$small-range: (0em, 40em);
$medium-range: (40.063em, 64em);
$large-range: (64.063em, 90em);
$xlarge-range: (90.063em, 120em);
$xxlarge-range: (120.063em);
```

As you can see there's a gap everywhere - for example the query ends at 64em and the next one begins only at 64.063em.

So the mobile nav would change state to desktop at 64em what converts to 1024px width but some other elements would appear only from 64.063em what's about 1027px?

I've edited the variables and fixed it but i wonder why would they do it like that?

Comment: All I would think of is a slacking browser causing delays, the creator of these ranges probably put the same **gap** between all to make it look consistent. There could be different reasons tho - this is just a scenario, I don't know for sure.

Comment: The only people who can answer this question are the maintainers of Foundation.  An answer from anyone else would be pure speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Technically `64.063em` should be `1025px` on almost all browsers unless you've tweaked the base font size somehow. You'll note here from their docs they include the values in the comments (trimmed for easier reading):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64em) { } /* min-width 641px and max-width 1024px */

@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) { } /* min-width 1025px, large screens */
```

You'll notice that they reference `1024px` and `1025px`. There is a chance that a browser could render that value slightly differently and cause a discrepancy. I would open up an issue on Github: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues